# SSIS job suddenly reporting syntax errors that aren't there

Tags: c#, ssis

I had a SSIS job that has been humming along fine and dandy until this week.  When I look at the output, it tells me this:

```
Error: 2021-04-21 15:33:08.74
   Code: 0xC0047062
   Source: Update AI_USER Update AI_USER (Get Admin Data [108])
   Description: Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package. Open the package in SSIS Designer and resolve the compilation errors.
End Error
Error: 2021-04-21 15:33:08.74
   Code: 0xC0047062
   Source: Update AI_USER Update AI_USER (Get Admin Data [108])
   Description: CS1514 - { expected, main.cs, 218, 36
End Error
```

But when I go to the line in question in Visual Studio, I see no missing brace:

```
            catch (WebException e) when (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
            {
                retryCount++;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do about this.  Anyone experience anything like this?

Comment: Is it possible the code you are reviewing is not the same code deployed? [Package Last Modified Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884700/find-ssis-package-last-modified-deployed-date-sql-server)

Comment: So what changed? Bits don't rot so it would see someone has updated the deployed packages on you, right?

Comment: I think the connection to the server is not working.  Check your connection string and see what server is being used.  If you are using DCHP the IP address of a machine changes periodically.  So you should use the computer name in the conneciton string instead of an IP address.